# How to make a web api service authenticated using AZURE

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-authorization

I am having two projects under one solution. one is for UI which is MVC and another one is WEB API service. I want to make the WEB API service to be authenticated as well as authorized during the call from the UI project inside the WEB API project.

Please share your stuffs on the above item, as i am so much confused on having the solution from the existing links.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you looking for? Integration with AzureAD?

Comment: Hey Prasanth. Did you have a look at Auth0? If so, could you mark this as answered? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for authentication. I use it extensively in similar architectures as you described e.g. separate UI project with separate back end API project. In my case I use Angular for the front end, and ASP.NET Web API for the back end with Auth0 sort of being the glue that holds the security together.

Their [docs](https://auth0.com/docs) are very good with lots of downloadable samples for most of the common stacks.

Basically, the front end talks to Auth0 platform and gets a token. This token is then used in any authenticated calls to the web api, therefore decoupling the security and the main functionality of the app.

And it's free for a lot of use cases! Win win!